# extract specific set of digits from random strings in EXCEL VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, digits

Disclaimer- my case is specific, and in my case my code works because I know the pattern.

I was looking for an answer everywhere, and the codes I tried were not quite what I was looking for, this is my solution if you are looking for a set of numbers.
In my case, I was looking for 7 digits, starting with digit `1` in a a column with random strings, some string had the number some others didn't.

The number will appear in these three scenarios "1XXXXXX", "PXXXXXXXX", "PXXXXXXXXX"(this has more digits because there is a slash).

Here are the examples of strings:

```
9797 P/O1743061 465347  Hermann Schatte Earl Lowe          
9797 Po 1743071 404440  Claude Gaudette Jose Luis Lopez     
9817 1822037    463889  Jean Caron  Mickelly Blaise
```

***My Code***

```
Sub getnum()

'i don't use explicit so i didn't declare everything
Dim stlen As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim arra() As String
Dim arran() As String

Orig.AutoFilterMode = False
Call BeginMacro

LastRow = Orig.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Orig.Range("J2:J" & LastRow).Clear

'loop though column
For n = 2 To LastRow
    celref = Orig.Cells(n, 4).Value
    'split string on white spaces
    arra() = Split(celref, " ")
    'turn string to multiple strings
    For counter = LBound(arra) To UBound(arra)
        strin = arra(counter)

        'remove white spaces from string
        storage = Trim(strin)
        lenof = Len(storage)

        'if string has 9 characthers, check for conditions
        If lenof = 9 Then
            'position of first and last charachter
            somstr = Mid(storage, 1, 1)
            somot = Mid(storage, 9, 1) 

            If somstr = "P" Or somstr = "p" And IsNumeric(somot) = True Then
                'removes Po or PO and keeps only 7 digits
                storage = Right(storage, 7)
                'stores in column J
                Orig.Cells(n, 10).Value = storage
            End If

        ElseIf lenof = 10 Then
            somstr = Mid(storage, 1, 1)
            somot = Mid(storage, 10, 1)

            'other conditions
            If somstr = "P" Or somstr = "p" And IsNumeric(somot) = True Then
                'removes Po or PO and keeps only 7 digits
                storage = Right(storage, 7)
                'stores in column J
                Orig.Cells(n, 10).Value = storage
            End If
        End If

        'eliminate comma within
        arran() = Split(storage, ",")

        If Orig.Cells(n, 10).Value <> storage Then
            For counter2 = LBound(arran) To UBound(arran)
                strin2 = arran(counter2)
                storage2 = Trim(strin2)

                'final condition if is 7 digits and starts with 1
                If IsNumeric(storage2) = True And Len(storage2) = 7 Then
                    car = Mid(storage2, 1, 1)

                    If car = 1 Then
                        'stores in columns J at specific position
                        Orig.Cells(n, 10).Value = storage2
                    End If
                Else
         If isnumeric(orig.cells(n,10).value) =true and _ 
             len(orig.cells(n,10).value = 7 then
                        orig.cells(n,10).value = orig.cells(n,10).value 
                        else
                    Orig.Cells(n, 10).Value = "no po# in D"
                End If
            Next counter2
        End If
    Next counter
Next n

Call EndMacro

End Sub
```

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363411/extract-largest-numeric-sequence-from-string-regex-or/49431766#49431766), please.

Comment: You can use `RegEx` object, with looking for 7 digits `Pattern = "\d{7}"`

Comment: Regexp need to reference external libs, break your mind and very-very slow. On the real DB witj hundreds of thousands of records you will enjoy :)

Comment: @MarY Am I right that all three scenarios patterns has leading space? May it be Chr(160) or not?

Comment: @MarY There no pattern for 'Po 1743071' . Nor for lowcased "O", nor for folowing space. WTF?!

Comment: @ user6698332 In this specific case, I don't need to have PO or Po , by isolating the 'p' alone or 'P', I get all the cases, I'm not going to write something I don't need....at the end, the code works, I used it, and got all the digits I needed. but this is very specific. If you use it, you need to check the restrictions you have in your strings.

Comment: Whether you use explicit or not you should always declare your variables. Also, you declare "i" but don't use it in your code.

Comment: What column are you putting the numbers?

Comment: @GMalc true, is a bad habit of mine. I put it in the comments, it's in column J AKA  .cells(n, 10) where column to position 10 starting from the left.

Comment: I provide a different way to accomplish what i think you are trying to do. Could you tell me if i understood what you were trying to do with your code?

Comment: no because the strings are random, that's why I split it the whole string into smaller strings and I analyse each substring one by one, and if it corresponds to one of the three scenarios then it prints in in the J column. Then I go to the next cell in the column, It's complex because the pattern is not constant.

Comment: Don't know why I still have that minus 1 besides by question, since my code worked! My client was happy .. wtf lol It could have actually helped someone.

Comment: @MarY, did you try any of the given answers?

Comment: @DisplayName sorry this solved for me and im working on something else, but I will the answers below this evening and give the proper feedback. Thanks for the reminder!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the RegEx to extract the number in desired format.

Please give this a try...

```
Function Get10DigitNumber(ByVal Str As String) As String    
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RE
   .Global = False
   .Pattern = "1\d{6}"
End With
If RE.test(Str) Then
    Get10DigitNumber = RE.Execute(Str)(0)
End If
End Function
```

Then if you want to use this function on the worksheet itself, assuming your string is in A2, try this...

```
=Get10DigitNumber(A2)
```

OR

You may use this function in another sub routine/macro like this...

```
Debug.Print Get10DigitNumber(<pass your string variable here>)
```

**Edited Function:**

```
Function Get10DigitNumber(ByVal Str As String) As String
Dim RE As Object, Matches As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RE
   .Global = False
   .Pattern = "[Pp]?\/?[Oo]?(1\d{6})\b"
End With
If RE.test(Str) Then
    Set Matches = RE.Execute(Str)
    Get10DigitNumber = Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
End If
End Function
```

And use if as already described above.

Comment: This is almost perfect, it would only need a work around because it's also taking digits among digits  example 1181925567 it turns it into 1925567, but in my code, that must be ignored because it is part of another type of code# entirely. For this macro, the digits are either stand alone or they have a PO, po, PO, or P/O in front...

Comment: I have edited the function so that the function will extract only a standalone 7 digit number starting with 1 `OR` a seven digit number starting with 1 and prefixed with either "PO" or "po" or "P/O" or "p/o". Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub getnum()
    Dim position As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    With  Worksheets("Orig") ' change it to your actual sheet name
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, Columns("J"))
            .Replace what:="P/O", replacement:="P/O ", lookat:=xlPart
            For Each cell In .Cells
                position = InStr(cell.Text, " 1")
                If position > 0 Then cell.Value = Mid(cell.Value, position + 1, 7)
            Next
        End With
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: @MarY, any feedback?

Comment: I tried it, and doesn't work...It does only half of the job, it does retrieve the 7 digits but retrieve strings with 7 digtis that have dashes, it ignores the Pxxxxxxxx , well it's obvious from your code it is omitting that.Also, but only a detail, i needed the numbers to be transfer to another column, in my code i take what is in column D ans display the results in column J.

Answer (score 0):

This code paste two formulas one in column G and one in column J). The first formula checks for a "P" in the first character of the cell in column 2 and if there is a "P" it extracts the last 7 characters in the string and puts them in column G. The second formula checks if there is **not** a "P" and if not extracts the last 7 characters in the string and puts them in column J.

```
Sub Extract()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     ws.Range("G2:G" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(LEFT(B2)=""P"",(RIGHT(B2,7)),"""")"
     ws.Range("J2:J" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(LEFT(B2)<>""P"",(RIGHT(B2, 7)),"""")"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the type of result your code gives 060-428
0-B0391,
01-2018,
060-428
01-2018
0-B0478,
03-2018, So nope doesn't work at all! Not even partially. 
Also, you can't use 1Row in vba it gets mixed up when you use it in a formula because of the digit.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your examples were in multiple cells. It is "lRow" not "1Row".

Answer (score 0):

After understanding what you were doing, I think this will work. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
Dim cell As Range, LRow As Long
LRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Range("D2:D" & LRow)
        If cell.Value Like "*Po *" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Split(cell.Value, " ")(2)

        Else: cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Split(cell.Value, " ")(1)

        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range("J2:J" & LRow)
        If Len(cell.Value) > 7 Then
            cell.Value = Right(cell.Value, 7)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Your code gives me 4 extra sets, that is because they are among other digits. But this helped me see that my code had two mistakes, which I corrected, didn't notice I misused the mid function. to find the last digit. Also, changed the last else, i embedded antoher if inside...